# is it possible to point multiple domains to the same site according to the country

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, web-hosting

For ex.

**if i open the website in india than url should be www.xyz.in

and if i open website in USA than url should be www.xyz.us**

so both the domain must show same content.  is it possible? or there will be some issues regarding duplicate content. please guide me. thank you.

if is it possible than possible by php,htaccess or jquery script?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can achieve it using php, htaccess and some Geo ip database. @ajay

Comment: Avin unless you are going to give details, such a general response is useless.

Comment: thanx @AvinVarghese how can i implement that using PHP or htaccess. can u please show me some script for ex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set your A-records to point those domains to the same machine. Then, in apache (I'm assuming apache), where you have your ServerName directive, also set a ServerAlias.

```
ServerName www.xyz.in
ServerAlias www.xyz.us
```

ServerAlias may also contain wildcards:

```
ServerAlias www.xyz.*
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be what you want, but, if you have access to both of the domain's A records, you could point both of them to the same server IP so the content is the same between both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on mobile:

http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/

Also, this article talks about doing it using the IP address and the [Maxmind GeoIP database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home):

> To find out where a certain phone number is from, you use a phone
>   book. To find out where an IP is from, you can use the Maxmind GeoIP
>   database. Maxmind also provides a JavaScript solution that you can use
>   on websites:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/08/entering-the-wonderful-world-of-geo-location/

Comment: The problem with client-side redirection is that it most often destroys the back button.

Comment: @joeframbach If you mean `location.replace` in Javascript, then yes. Otherwise, I have no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: Yes that is what I am referring to. Sorry, I had a knee-jerk reaction to "Maxmind also provides a JavaScript solution that you can use on websites"

Answer (score 0):

First you must choose a primary domain. Update your A-records as @joeframbach mentioned.

track the user country code using Maxmind or some other GeoIP database. Then redirect the user to their country domain.

```
if ( country == "us" ) {
    header('Location: http://www.xyz.us/');
}
```